# How to set the distance between nodes in react-vis-force?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vis.js, vis.js-network, react-vis

I am having troble in figuring out, how to set the distance between nodes in react-vis-force. 
Is there anyway to dynamically set link length based on the individual link? For example, some nodes are further apart than others.

Comment: have you tried my answer? did it help?

Comment: Hi @YakovL , i tried , but it didn't worked for me. I choose a different plugin which served my purpose. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I see. Would be nice of you if you share your solution in form of another answer (and accept it when SO allows to do so)

Answer (score 0):

[Edges](http://visjs.org/docs/network/edges.html) have the `length` property, have you tried that? If you define edges using `vis.DataSet` like this

```
edges = new vis.DataSet([edge1, edge2, ..]);
```

modifying `edges[i].length` should do the trick.